# force last div on a new line with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
     <div class="one"></div>
     <div class="two"></div>
     <div class="three"></div>
     <div class="four"></div>
</div>
```

plus this CSS

```
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.one {
    flex: 0 1 200px;
}

.two {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.three {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 200px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.four {
    ???
}
```

and i wanna make it look like this, i don't know what else to use for .four to make that last div to move on a new line plus 100% width

```
[- one -----][----- two -----][----- three -]
[----------------- four --------------------]
```

atm looks like this

```
[- one -----][----- two -----][----- three -] [- four -----]
```

i know i can use another

```
<div class="wrap">
```

but i don't want this,
Thank you.

Comment: You could just use the html tag `<br/>` to move it to the next line.

Comment: using `<br/><div class="four"></div>` will do the same.

Answer (score 20):

Add `flex-wrap: wrap` to the `.wrap` class, and make your `.four` class `flex: 1 1 100%`, that should do the trick:

```
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.one {
    flex: 0 1 200px;
}

.two {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.three {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 200px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.four {
   flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

Here's a [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJKbqe) (I added a border and height to your divs just to make it easier to visualise).

Comment: damn, Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it worked for you :)

Comment: @delinear why have you applied `display: flex` in `.two` and `.three` class? I don't think there is need of this

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt I haven't applied them - those are OP's styles from the question, I just duplicated his code and added the additional styles to .wrap and .four.

Comment: @delinear but if you are giving an answer I think you have to remove the code which is not useful and inform the OP

Comment: @Bhuwan Bhatt i used `display: flex` in .two because in .two i actualy have another 3 divs and they need to be in-line and for .three i use it because i had to apply `justify-content: flex-end;`

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt OP had a very specific question, which I answered to his satisfaction. I assumed anything not related to his question was there for a reason and the solution should work _alongside_ the existing code (which OP has confirmed to be the case).

Answer (score 0):

Please check you can try this

```
<div class="wrap">
     <div class="one"></div>
     <div class="two"></div>
     <div class="three"></div>
     <div class="four"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrap > div{
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 200px;
}

.one {
    flex: 0 1 200px;
}

.two {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.three {
    flex: 0 1 200px;
}

.four {
    flex: 100%;
}
```

link https://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/eoat01zn/

Answer (score 0):

this is simple:
To achieve this:

```css
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
}
.one, .two, .three{
width: 33%;
background:red;
}

.four{
width:100%;
background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">
    one 
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    two
  </div>
  <div class="three">
  three
  </div>
  <div class="four">
  four
  </div>
</div>
```